# ¿Por que al intentar cambiar una variable dentro de un TimerTask me da error?

Tags: java

En la ***linea 13*** (**dormir = true;**) me dice el

> Syntax error on token "dormir", VariableDeclaratorId expected after this token.

```js
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Comprobacion {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
     
     boolean dormir = false;
     
     TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
      dormir = true;
      int cont = 0;
         @Override
         public void run() {
    cont++;
    System.out.println("Contador: "+cont);
         }
     };
     
        ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        
     int tiempoDeInicio = 1, tiempoDeIntervalo = 1;
     
        scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, tiempoDeInicio, tiempoDeIntervalo, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
}
```

Comment: Mira la actualizacion de mi respuesta y dime si lograste tu cometido.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que la variable `dormir` está declarada de manera local y cambiando el valor en el espacio de la clase `TimerTask`. Por lo tanto, te pide una declaración.

Con el `cont` no te da problemas, porque si lo estas declarando. Si quieres cambiar esa variable dentro de la subclase, debes hacerlo dentro de algún metodo de la misma o fuera de su contexto:

```
// dormir = true; antes de llamar el TimerTask es valido
TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
            // dormir = true; lanza error porque asume una declaracion
            int cont = 0; // este es valido porque se declara como parte de TimerTask
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // dormir = true; aqui es valido si es static y global
                cont++;
                System.out.println("Contador: "+cont);
            }
        };
```

Viendolo como una clase estas haciendo esto:

```
public class TimerTask {
       dormir = true; 
       . . .
}
```

Y obviamente al hacer eso en una clase te lanzará un error de sintaxis aclarandote que debes especificar el tipo.

Intenta hacer esto:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Comprobacion {

    private static boolean dormir = false;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
            int cont = 0;
            @Override
            public void run() {
                dormir = true;
                cont++;
                System.out.println("Contador: "+cont);
            }
        };

        ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

        int tiempoDeInicio = 1, tiempoDeIntervalo = 1;

        scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, tiempoDeInicio, tiempoDeIntervalo, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok. ¿Como podría manipular una variable fuera del **TimerTask**?

Comment: @PabloContreras te refieres en el espacio de la clase `TimerTask` (donde está `cont`)? Qué es lo que quieres lograr?. Puedes intentar declarar dormir como parte de la clase Comprobacion (global).

Comment: manipular una variable con una comprobación cada segundo, se supone q dentro del **TimerTask()** hare una funcion para comprobar algo, pero necesito modificar una variable externa.

Comment: @PabloContreras mira el código que puse en mi respuesta. Puedes declarar la variable global. Y esa variable al ser externa, como es global puedes cambiar su valor y utilizarla fuera y dentro de TimerTask a merced. Se declara static porque los métodos estáticos requieren variables estáticas. Y main es static.

Comment: Gracias hermano, lo que necesitaba.